# ColdFusion 11 start-up slow over the network

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I recently installed ColdFusion 11.

Unconnected from a network, it takes 12seconds to start.

Connected to a network and the Internet it takes six and a half minutes!

1. What’s taking so long?
2. How do I switch this slow network call off?
3. How do I debug this kind of problem?

Many Thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to answer check the network activity using some wireshark then you may get some lead

Comment: Better suited to ServerFault

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, as it happens to me too. Hopefully it gets re-raised on serverfault, and followed up. I suspect Adobe is attempted to phone home, but is being blocked by our firewall..?

Comment: Here is the bug# https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3772978. You need to apply the hf1100-3776060.jar hotfix and the issue will be resolved. In case, one needs the hotfix, they need to contact Adobe at cf.install@adobe.com

Comment: Anit- that's the right answer. I applied the fix and it worked. Because this topic is currently on-hold, I can't mark this as answered.